# Count where for an indexedDB database

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexeddb

I am storing dates in an indexedDB database and I want to count the number of records that happened in 2018, 2017 etc and print them out in a table. The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how to check the dates against the previous records to count them cleanly. Its sort of the equivalent to a count where function is SQL.

At first, I had something like this but I'm not sure it's going to work. The dates are being stored like so 'Wed Jan 05 2018' hence the use of the Slice() method.

```
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        //2016
        firstPostYear = cursor.value.date.slice(-4);
        alert(firstPostYear);
        var count = 0;

        if (cursor)
        {
            if (cursor.value.date.slice(-4) === firstPostYear)
            {
                count += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(count);
                count = 0;
                firstPostYear = cursor.value.date.slice(-4)
            }

            cursor.continue()
        }
```

If somebody could show me a simpler way to do this, I would appreciate it.

This is for Ryan:

```
function filterSelection(filter) 
{
    var objectStore = db.transaction('posts').objectStore('posts');

objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) 
{
    var cursor = event.target.result;

    if (filter === "all")
    {    
        //Get the number of all time posts
        var transaction = db.transaction(['posts'], 'readonly');
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('posts');

        var countRequest = objectStore.count();
        countRequest.onsuccess = function() 
        {
            // Get table element
            var table = document.getElementById("activityLog");
            //Get table length
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            // Create a table row
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            // Insert new cells positions 1-5 of the "new" <tr> element:
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

            // Add some text to the new cells:
            cell1.innerHTML = "All time";
            cell2.innerHTML = countRequest.result;
        }

    }

    else if (filter === "Years")
    {
        //Get the number of posts each year
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        var counts = {};

        if (cursor) 
        {
            const year = cursor.value.date.slice(-4);

            if ( !(year in counts) ) 
            {
                counts[year] = 0;
            }
            (counts[year]) + 1;
            alert(counts[year]);

            cursor.continue();

        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't entirely know what the object store that holds this data looks like, so I might be making some assumptions regarding it and what you are doing.

First off, there is one better way to do what you're doing than opening up a cursor and iterating over the whole store. If you could restructure your data at all, you could create a field that stores the object's year, create an index on that field, and essentially do `<ObjectStoreReference>.index('year').count()` to get all the documents very quickly.

But if you can't, then you'll need to do it this way. However, the way you are tracking the information right now using the cursor approach won't let you print out everything in a table, because each time the year you generate from `cursor.value.date.slice(-4)` changes from your `firstPostYear`, you clear your count.

You could try doing something like

```
const counts = {};

if (cursor) {
    const year = cursor.value.date.slice(-4);
    if ( !(year in counts) ) {
        counts[year] = 0;
    }
    counts[year]++;
    cursor.continue();
}
```

And then you can loop over the entries in the object and print out each year and its count however you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to change the data structure. On your example when I alert count after incrementing I get a value of 0. No matter how many records have the same year

Comment: Can you share your code (either inline or in a Gist/JSFiddle, etc.)? I image the problem might be that you are initializing `counts` inside the `onsuccess` handler of opening your cursor, in which case `cursor.continue()` is re-initializing it on each successive iteration. You probably need to create `counts = {}` one level higher than the success handler.

Comment: I have added it along the bottom of my question

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is with this line: `(counts[year]) + 1;` You're simply adding the number contained in `counts[year]` to 1, but not assigning the result to anywhere. What happens if you change it to `counts[year] += 1`?

Comment: Yeah. I should have noticed that one. The current data is 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018. Meaning the alerts should be 1, 2, 1, 2 but I'm getting the result 1, 1, 1, 1. I'm guessing this means the if statement isn't working?

Comment: Because `var` is scoped to a function, I wonder if running `cursor.continue()` is causing `counts` to be reset. What happens if you declare `var counts = {}` as the very first line of your `filterSelection` function (right above this line: `var objectStore = db.transaction('posts').objectStore('posts');`)?

Comment: That's got it. Thanks for your help